# How to apply filter on data of table records in descending order using checkbox in Angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-filter

i am trying to implement search records depends on drop-down and also want to apply records in descending order using checkbox  but my checkbox is not working when i am click on it.

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js">

```
<h1>Search Filter aesc/desc</h1>

<select ng-model="strcolumn">
    <option value="sname">NAME</option>
    <option value="course">COURSE</option>
    <option value="fee">FEE</option>
</select>

<input type="checkbox" name = "isReverse" ng-model="isReverse">

<table border="2px solid green" ng-controller="stuCtrl">
<tr>
<td>NAME</td>
<td>COURSE</td>
<td>FEE</td>
</tr>

<tr ng-repeat="item in ar | orderBy:strcolumn : isReverse ">
<td>{{item.sname|uppercase}}</td>
<td>{{item.course}}</td>
<td>{{item.fee|currency}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: please re-format your question, and put a jsfiddle or plunkr link to your question, would be easier to help you that way.

Comment: sorry my code is not formatted but actully i don't know how to put  jsfiddle or plunkr link in my code and also don't have idea how to put all code icluding html and script tag in my code.please help me

Comment: Ok, no problem. You add all your code here, I ll format it for you :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem you're facing is that both your dropdown and checkbox are in a different controller (if any at all?). Notice how you're attaching `stuCtrl` to a `<table>` element, leaving inputs out of it?

What I did is wrapped your whole code with a `<div>` and moved the controller declaration there. Here's a working example at CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdQLWW.

The code would look like this:

```
<div ng-controller="stuCtrl">
  <h1>Search Filter aesc/desc</h1>

  <select ng-model="strcolumn">
    <option value="sname">NAME</option>
    <option value="course">COURSE</option>
    <option value="fee">FEE</option>
  </select>

  <input type="checkbox" name="isReverse" ng-model="isReverse">

  <table border="2px solid green">
    <tr>
      <td>NAME</td>
      <td>COURSE</td>
      <td>FEE</td>
    </tr>

    <tr ng-repeat="item in ar | orderBy:strcolumn : isReverse ">
      <td>{{item.sname|uppercase}}</td>
      <td>{{item.course}}</td>
      <td>{{item.fee|currency}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Glad it helped. Would you mind accepting the answer then?